# LaTeX editor with seamless auto-complete

Tags: texstudio, kile, auto-completion

When working on a LaTeX project I like to create an `.sty` file (say `mymacros.sty`) where all my custom macros are defined. I then simply call
`\usepackage{mymacros}` in the main `.tex` file preamble. I also update `mymacros.sty` while working when I need to define a new macro.

The drawback is that most LaTeX editors I have tried can auto-complete commands directly in the preamble of the main `.tex` file but cannot auto-complete commands from `mymacros.sty`.

*TeXStudio* autogenerates a `.cwl` file corresponding to `mymacros.sty` but marks all commands with `#S` (i.e. do not show in completer at all). Okay, I could simply replace these with `#n` for example and everything would be fine. However, when updating `mymacros.sty` for a new command, the `.cwl` file is not updated correspondingly. I would have to manually insert the new command to the `.cwl` file.

*Kile* does auto-complete commands for `mymacros.sty` but, for some reason, only some of them. I haven't been able to find out why.

**My question:**

Is there an editor which would provide the described functionality out-of-the-box? That would be able automatically parse the used packages and offer auto-completion of its commands even when the package is regularly updated?

**Specifically:**

- I do not want to be editing any .cwl files.
- I'm fine with all the commands being classified as #n as long as they appear in the auto-complete pop-up window.

Comment: While this would be a great feature, it's pretty hard to do this for arbitrary packages (and I'm not aware of any editor doing this). Think of `\csname` constructions and the different options to define macros (`\def`/`\gdef`, …, `\newcommand`, …, `\NewDocumentCommand`, …, `\cs_set:Npn`, …). Therefore you might focus on an editor you really want to use and open a feature request there.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem!! Here is the solution:

Add the command `\ProcessOptions\relax` at the end of your `.sty` or `.cls` file. Then reopen the cwl created by txs and you will find txs has already added all the `#include ...`commands automatically!!!